# How to handle pathScan decoding of url encoded parameters?

Tags: f#, suave

I have something like :-

```
 pathScan "/blah/%s" (fun x) -> (sprintf "%A"  x) |> json)
```

and what it shows me if I  do  `/blah/AT%2BVER%3F` is the url encoded data.  Is there a way to get this decoded automatically?  or do I need to parse all my parameters ( which seems a bit odd )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some older versions require manually decoding.  Note that a [pull request was accepted](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/pull/393) (and is now in the current release) which should address this in the next release.

Currently, the best option is to either upgrade to the latest Suave or run this through [System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) yourself (as this is the mechanism being used by Suave vCurrent).

Comment: great, that's what I did, it just felt a bit odd.  Good to see there's a PR to handle this.

Comment: Correction: that PR was accepted on Feb. 22, 201**6**, a year ago. So it should already be in Suave version 2. @KeithNicholas, which Suave version are you using?